# Ubuntu with KDE and kernel 3.6.2 - performance issues

Tags: kde, performance

I have recently swiched to Ubuntu and installed KDE on it.
I like software included in Ubuntu but interface from Kubuntu.

My problem is, that after installation of Linux kernel 3.6.2 (default Ubuntu 12.04 is 3.2 I think), whole KDE interface is laggy and I have to render using Xrender because OpenAL doesn't work.

So please tell me, I didint find it anywhere, Does KDE has some problems with new kernel? should I downgrade back to 3.x.x?

Thank you for answers and your time.

Pelda

Comment: please excuse missclicks - Open AL*, Xrender*, .......

Answer (score 0):

when you login u can choose old kernel on GRUB menu with advance menu and open konsole

1. You can check your current used kernel with this command:

   ```
   uname -r
   ```
2. To find a list of all installed kernels on your system, run this command:

   ```
   dpkg --list | grep linux-image
   ```
3. To remove all unused kernels, run now this command:

   ```
   sudo aptitude purge ~ilinux-image-\[0-9\]\(\!`uname -r`\)
   ```

   In case `aptitude` is not installed, then install it with this command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install aptitude
   ```
4. Update now your Grub2 boot loader with this command:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```